# In Python, cannot import current modules after adding the importing root path

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a project below.

```
project/
├ main/
  ├ modules/
    ├ moduleA.py
├ test/
  ├ testA.py
  ├ modules/
    ├ moduleC.py
```

I programed `moduleA.py` and `moduleC.py` below.

```
# moduleA.py
def funcA():
  print("A")
```

```
# moduleC.py
def funcC():
  print("C")
```

In the situation that I want to test `moduleA.funcA()` with `moduleC.funcC()` in `testA.py`, I'm worried about the code importing `moduleC.funcC()` to `testA.py`.

```
import inspect
import os
import sys
PYPATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + "/"
sys.path.append(PYPATH + "./../")
from main.modules.moduleA import funcA # This is OK.

# from test.modules.moduleC import funcC # ModuleNotFoundError
from modules.moduleC import funcC # This is OK.

if __name__ == "__main__":
  funcA()
  funcC()
```

I want to import `funcC()` to `testA.py` with `from test.modules.moduleC import funcC`.

Would you say this is feasible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is the value of PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @NicholasHunter
Thank you for your commenting!
But there is no PYTHONPATH because I want use paths only when running `.py`.

Comment: You are able to import the function using **from modules.moduleC import funcC**. Why do you want to use a different statement to do the same thing? Also, you don't want to use PYTHONPATH, but you want to achieve the same results using what looks to me like a deeply suspect manipulation of sys.path at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because python already has a module named **test**, and there is no **modules** module in python's **test**. Therefore rename **test** directory to something else will works. or change the **sys.path**'s default order

Comment: Your answer helped me!
Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's completely viable. Python defines two types of packages, regular packages and namespace packages. Regular packages are traditional packages as they existed in Python 3.2 and earlier. A regular package is typically implemented as a directory containing an '**init**.py' file. When a regular package is imported, this '**init**.py' file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace. The '**init**.py' file can contain the same Python code that any other module can contain, and Python will add some additional attributes to the module when it is imported.